# Loading from Assimp(Pyassimp) to pyglet - bad results

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, assimp

So I'm learning OpenGL using pyglet and I'm importing some models from Blender using Assimp ( port: Pyassimp). So the scene is really basic, it is just 2 cubes and I'm saving it in blend format.In the next piece of code I'm just trying to draw one cube simply using its vertex positions, nothing else.

```
     self.scene = pyassimp.load(FILENAME, pyassimp.postprocess.aiProcess_Triangulate)  # Load the scene

    self.vertices = numpy.array((), dtype=GLfloat)
    for v in self.scene.meshes[1].vertices:
        self.vertices = numpy.append(self.vertices, v)

    self.vbo = pyglet.graphics.vertexbuffer.create_buffer(self.vertices.nbytes, GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    self.vbo.bind()
    self.vbo.set_data(self.vertices.ctypes.data)
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0)
```

And next piece of code is the draw event:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, self.lightfv(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, self.lightfv(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, self.lightfv(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, self.lightfv(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0))


    glTranslated(0, 10, -25)
    glRotatef(self.rotation, 0, 1, 0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(self.model.vertices))
```

Finally the result:

[image: Not a cube]

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the faces of the mesh, read the vertex index from there and then draw the faces.

See the C example of assimp. It's quite simple, shows how to do and can very easy be ported to python.
https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/samples/SimpleOpenGL/Sample_SimpleOpenGL.c

For `pyglet` you can use the following snipped:

```
    for node in self.scene.rootnode.children:
        glPushMatrix()
        glMultMatrixf((GLfloat * 16)(*node.transformation.transpose().flatten()))

        for mesh in node.meshes:
            for face in mesh.faces:
                num_indices = len(face)
                if num_indices == 1:
                    mode = GL_POINTS
                elif num_indices == 2:
                    mode = GL_LINES
                elif num_indices == 3:
                    mode = GL_TRIANGLES
                else:
                    mode = GL_POLYGON

                pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(len(mesh.vertices), mode, face, ('v3f', mesh.vertices.flatten()))

        glPopMatrix()
```